# How to disable keyboard but having the scroll function intact in UITextView?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview, scrollview

I am displaying logs in the scroll-able text view, I want to retain this functionality but disable the keyboard. I have tried the unchecking in Behaviour of the Attribute Inspector, but it disables the scroll view too.

Can anyone guide me what options I have?

Comment: Use **textview** control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `editable` property of `UITextView` to `NO` or `FALSE`. GOod Luck!

Comment: No, it does not. Try that.